# Receiving data from X3 Concox GPS device using Python

Tags: python, django, sockets, gps, geocoding

I have a project where I'm trying to receive data from X3 GPS device using python socket. And so far i have managed to create listening script with both port number and IP address configured.

```
s= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
host =  '192.XX.XX.XX'
port = 1234

s.bind((host,port))
s.listen()

print(f'listening ...')

while True:
 conn, address = s.accept()
 print(f'connection from {address} has been establish')
```

And i also configured the IP and the port number to the device via SMS.
**BUT I can't get it to connect.**
I need a help to connect the device first before starting receiving login packets or if there are better solutions for the same issue using python.

Comment: A lot of people here don't know about this X3 GPS device. Does it have documentation?

Comment: There's a GSM connected GPS tracker named "X3". In combination with the `192.` which could be a private IP I suspect a networking issue. That would be out of the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Its gps device with the ability to operate via sms commands, that mean you can get GPS locations, status and other  and also it can send data to a desired location you just have to provide the IP AND PORT NUMBER different features integrated you can read more here https://www.iconcox.com/products/x3-multifunctional-vehicle-tracker.html.

Comment: Mr. Klaus I wrote 192.X.X.X  meaning that it can be any valid  IP Address.